# HP ENVY Phoenix 800-019eb Desktop PC (ENERGY STAR)(E3H43EA)

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, integrated-graphics

I want to buy this amazing PC but I want to extend this PC with a GTX 680. Is this possible?

Because [this PC](http://www8.hp.com/be/nl/products/desktops/product-detail.html?oid=5391123#!tab=specs) has standard a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680 with Intel HD Graphics 4600 (GT2) integrated graphics.

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=5358985&prodTypeId=12454&prodSeriesId=5358985&objectID=c03802614

Comment: It already comes with a GTX 680 which means that a second card will be unable to fit in the case.

Comment: Yes I know it already haves a GTX 680, but I want 2 of them so that I can have 4GB dedicated graphic memory. Is there no slot free for another GTX 680?

Comment: The motherboard clearly per the specifications only has a single PCIEx16 slot.  As I indicated beyond the fact you don't have the required PCIEx16 slot it wouldn't be able to fit 2 cards in the case nor provide 2 of those cards enough power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

There's basically two ways you can use a pair of video cards, and both require 2 physical x16 slots, running at at least x8. This has one, and a bunch of x1 slots.

Some folk HAVE used risers to put video cards into lesser PCI slots, but in your case, that would be pointless - the video card will likely saturate a single PCIe channel.

There's simply no room for it on that motherboard.